# Laravel 9 auto increment, how to fill number gap first before auto counting + 1?

Tags: php, laravel, math

In the `blade` form I get the latest/highest number from the database and add it by 1 when creating new data:

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control @error('ir_number') is-invalid @enderror" name="ir_number" placeholder="IR Number"
   value="{{ DB::table('cases_reports')->get('ir_number', $report->ir_number)->max('ir_number') + 1 }}"/>
```

It's working as it should, but how can I specify to fill up the gaps between numbers first?

`e.g. 1 - 5. create 2, 3, 4 first before creating 6`

Also, sometimes the user deletes a record, how can I also fill that deleted number then continue counting?

Comment: Recycling values from an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field is not recommended. What is your reason for wanting such functionality, what are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: I say auto increment, yet it's not to the ```id```. I am not working with the ```primary key```. the ```ir_number``` is already unique so now I want whenever the user creates a new invoice, it adds the last invoice number by 1. ```e.g. If last number is 001, then make 002.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to reuse identifiers, primary `auto_increment` or not. That value should represent the unique identity a single `entity` and recycling values will inevitably cause conflicts/confusion.

Consider your scenario for invoicing. Someone generates an invoice which is assigned a non database derived `ir_number` of `001`. A few more invoices are generated and now you're at `005`. The invoice with `ir_number` `003` is deleted, but that invoice has been generated and so *someone* has an invoice with that `ir_number`.

A new invoice is generated and your application determines that `003` is available for reuse and so assigns this new invoice an `ir_number` of `003`. You now have **two** invoices with the same `ir_number`. So if someone has a concern with invoice `003`, which one is it?

Additionally, consider the scenario where two invoices are being generated simultaneously. This could result in a deadlock/race condition trying to retreive or use the next available `ir_number`. You *could* do some validation and/or additional checks before and during creation, but that is additional work.

Consider what it is you're attempting to achieve, does it *really* make sense to reuse `ir_number`?